# Did Harry not collect all of Snape's tear in DH 2?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In Snape's death scene, Snape gives Harry his memories in the form of a tear. Now in the scene right when Harry turns back around from grabbing Hermonine's flask and puts it up to Snape's tear, another tear falls. Some is collected but there is a notable amount of magical tear left on Snape's cheek. Snape doesn't release any tears out of the other eye, only his left eye, so does every part of these tears contain memories? By Harry not collecting both tears does that mean that Harry was supposed to see more from Snape and didn't? Are there more Snape memories that were meant to be seen?

Comment: For Polyjuice Potion, a single hair contains the complete essence of a person, regardless of the hair's length.  Memory tears might work similarly, so that the loss of a tear might not mean the loss of a memory.

Comment: That is a good point! The thought that any part of the tear would be the whole memory had crossed my mind but I wasn't sure. That is a great point about Polyjuice Potion!

Comment: I am really starting to get afraid that after 11 years the book series has completed its journey, more and more fans would theorize and consider "standard" the movie series and not the books. **What you describe *does not* happen in Book 7**. Nearly everything depicted in the movies that differ from the books are for the shake of cinematic essence and nothing more. Intuitively, the book series is what considered canon and the movies follow, **not** the other way around.

Comment: I understand your point, and you have the right to be upset if that is happening. I do not want that to happen either, but the movies did occur, and the choices they made were made with Jo watching and being involved as much as possible. Therefore after much editing and deciding which way to go for this monumental scene, the director chose this way of showing Snape's memories. I think it was an interesting decision and is what made me question it further. Especially since it is such a different take on the book.

Comment: **(1/3)** @JamieWright I disagree. JKR was hugely involved in the making of the first two films *only*, and that's the one of the two reasons why HP1 and HP2 are so closely connected to the books (the other being that they are relatively smaller novels than the rest five). Apart from minor alterations that served as to support the story of future movies (i.e. the symbol of the Deathly Hallows appearing as early as HP4 movie), all other differences are there only to give a more "cinematic" essence and nothing more.

Comment: **(2/3)** JKR didn't intervene in all those changes that did not negatively impact the story. For instance, every time two wizards duel, the *Priori Incantatem* event is triggered in all films after HP4, even though there's no case *all* those wizards share twin cores with their opponents. This was clearly not referenced in the books. JKR did intervened in other cases that would change the course of the story (Dumbledore being gay was revealed because the author forbid the inclusion of a woman love interest in HP6).

Comment: **(3/3)** Finally, keep in mind that something that is beautifully written in a book, does not necessarily make a great scene in a movie and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

An interesting theory, but there is no evidence to suggest Harry missed anything.

You may be intrigued to know that in the book there are a few more memories that Harry sees. Perhaps, (and this is purely conjecture on my part), the other tears are a nod to this, or at least a post justification.

Either way, I wouldn’t look too into it. As far as I have been able to tell, there is no hidden meaning behind the left over tears. That is to say, had Harry collected them, he would have seen the same set of memories.

Think of the tears as a vessel for memory, not the memory itself.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the knowledge! I am getting into the potterverse late in the game and while watching DH 2 I saw it and couldn't get it out of my head.

Comment: Well, feel free to ask me anything! I’m quite knowledgable on everything Potter :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the tears were an invention by the movie production. In the book, Snape uses his wand to draw a memory from his temple in the usual way, like we see Slughorn do in *Half-Blood Prince* and Dumbledore do on more than one occasion. So there would be nothing "missing" from the memory given to Harry (and as pointed out by Recelica, the book shows more of Snape's memories than the film).